# dotnet restore command in dockerfile fails : Invalid remote certificate : PartialChain

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

`dotnet restore` command in Dockerfile fails with the following message

The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-rc.1.23463.5/NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [api.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-rc.1.23463.5/NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
```

This is happening in Release mode but I dont see it Debug mode

Build image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that this is happening on corporate laptop with security tools installed (Zscaler).

Saw no issues while executing it from home PC.